# Exporting ASP.NET datagrid to Excel not showing color of datacell contents

Tags: asp.net, excel, datagrid

I am exporting an ASP.NET datagrid to excel and having an issue with the colors exporting with it. I know in order for the cells color to be exported to excel you must set the background color of the cell. I have several lines of text in the cell, parts of the text are wrapped in a div and the div background color is set. This is the color I need exported. Is there a way to do this? I have included an example below of what would be found in a cell.

```
<div style="background-color: #b88eb5;>
    Random Text 1
</div>
<div style="background-color: #8ccb83;>
    Random Text 2
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that both of these divs would occupy a single cell?  If that's the case, then what should the background color of the exported cell even be?  It can only be one.

Comment: Yes, both divs are in one cell. The cell does not have a background color, each div does. I want the color from the divs to be exported. I'm not sure if this can be done since I want the div background color and not the cell background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarification in comments, I don't believe this can be directly accomplished using built-in DataGrid export functionality.  Since the "background color" for any given cell is:

1. Held by a child element of the cell.
2. One of multiple colors from which to choose.

then transferring the correct background color to the output file is going to require custom export code.

Comment: I figured as much but was hoping there was a way around it. Thanks!